# Auto next activity with countdown timer not working with cancel method

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I try auto next activity with countdown timer but not work if use cancel method.

```
//Next Activity
  CountDownTimer myCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }
   public void onFinish() {
       Intent startActivity = new Intent(ActivityNew1.this,ActivityNew2.class);
       startActivity(startActivity);


   }

}.start();
myCountDownTimer.cancel();
```

Above java code auto next activity every 1s not working. And I try remove myCountDownTimer.cancel();

```
//Next Activity
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        public void onFinish() {
            Intent startActivity = new Intent(ActivityNew1.this,ActivityNew2.class);
            startActivity(startActivity);
            finish();
        }

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

    }.start();
```

This java code work for auto next activity but auto next activity run after back to home, auto next not stop.

---

Solved

I just Add this code on backpress method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent i = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
    i.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
    startActivity( i );
    finish();
    finishAffinity();
    System.exit( 0 );
}
```

Comment: @yakuk You should use Handler..

Comment: Can you tell what are you trying to do ? Above code will take you to the Activity2  once the time elapses as you have used Intent in onFinish() method of CountDownTimer.

Comment: I try next auto activity every second. but auto next can't stop if success open new activity.

Comment: You mean starting activity every second? If yes, what is the use of doing so?

Comment: thanks rahul... solved with method https://stackoverflow.com/a/48293623/9227433

Comment: Please don't give the answer inside your question. Instead, you need to create an answer then mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a global boolean variable

```
boolean isPause = false;
```

Declare countdown timer

```
MyCountDownTimer myCountDownTimer;
```

Initialize CountDownTimer

```
myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(5000, 1000);
myCountDownTimer.start();
```

Countdown Timer code

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

        public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if(isPause){
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ForgotPasswordActivity.class));
                myCountDownTimer.cancel();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
//            startActivity(new Intent(ConsumerHomeActivity.this, ForgotPasswordCustomerActivity.class));
        }


    }
```

When you want to cancel the timer, just do this

```
isPause = true;
```

and then the code in onTick will hit and you will be in next activity as countdown timer does not invoke onFinish method.

Comment: hi rahul, can you approved edit? I want hidden my project thanks

Comment: You want to hide your project code, its better if you remove it and if my answer helped you please accept the answer. Thanks